# How to have a progress bar display while a function is being processed (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, python-multithreading

I want to create a progress bar where when you press a button to call another function, the progress bar runs, then ends when that function is done. So press a button, progress bar goes for however long it takes that function to finish, then stops when that function has completed. This is what I have come up with so far, but I'm not sure why the progress bar doesn't start. Any advice or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
import time
import threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import randint

root = Tk()

root.geometry("250x250")

label = Label(root, text="")
label.pack(pady=20)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, length = 100, mode = "indeterminate")
progress_bar.pack(pady = 50)

def start_time():
    time.sleep(5)
    label.config(text="Done")

thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=start_time)

my_button1 = Button(root, text="Start", command=thread_1.start)
my_button1.pack(pady=20)

while thread_1.is_alive == False:
    progress_bar.start(10)
else:
    progress_bar.stop


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You wrote "the progress bar doesn't start", but I test your code and the progress bar starts, but it doesn't close when the thread is "Done"

Comment: Also don't call tkinter from multiple threads - tkinter might crash

Comment: Also why do you have `progress_bar.stop` shouldn't it be `progress_bar.stop()`?

Comment: Eventually you might run into `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop` while trying to multi thread tkinter.